# Serving WordPress in it's own directory on localhost on WAMP

Tags: localhost, apache

I have followed [Giving WordPress it's own directory](https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/#moving-a-root-install-to-its-own-directory) for directions on how to accomplish this on www.mysite.com (once it goes live) but I'm looking for localhost directions to serve my site to localhost directly with WordPress in a SubFolder (I don't think you change .htaccess for localhost).

My WordPress installation is at /sitefolder/arc/...

How can I browse to localhost and see my site as opposed to the way it is now, having to navigate to localhost/sitefolder/arc?

I am guessing its something in the DocumentRoot?

I am using WAMP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two alternatives:

1. Change the DocumentRoot directive in the WAMP httpd.conf file (use CTRL+F to find it). That way you will change the whole root folder of your server, be aware of that!
2. Create a virtual host that will bind a domain to a particular subfolder in your document root (similar to subdomains logic). Here some article that might help:

https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/create-virtual-hosts-in-a-wamp-server/

I personally prefer the second option, is better than modify the entire document root. With a virtual host you choose if you want to use the root or a subdirectory.

Be happy!

Comment: Hey, can you see my new question here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/340551/installing-wordpress-in-a-sub-folder-not-in-root-on-localhost , thanks, West