# Installing WordPress in a Sub-Folder (not in root) on Localhost

Tags: apache

I've given WordPress it's own directory in mysite/wordpress to try out some security things.

Using a WAMP on Localhost, I changed httpd.conf to:

```
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/mysite
 <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/mysite/">
```

and httpd-vhosts.conf to:

```
   DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/mysite"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/mysite/">
```

When I go to localhost, it says /index of /wordpress.

How do I get apache to serve the actual files (WordPress) inside the sub-directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use WordPress core settings for doing this?
This is the recommended way and doesn't need editing .htaccess or Apache config directly. You can find the details [here in WP docs](https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/). I'm posting the steps here:

- After installing WP in the root dir, Go to the `Settings->General` and change these values:
- WordPress Address (URL): `http://localhost/wordpress`
- Site Address (URL): `http://localhost`
- Save the settings and don't worry about the errors
- Move all WP files to the `wordpress` sub-directory.
- Copy (NOT MOVE!) the `index.php` and `.htaccess` files from the `wordpress` sub-directory into the root directory of your site
- Edit the `index.php` placed in the root and change the line that says:
  `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );`
  to the following:
  `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );`
- Login to WP using `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/`
- Go to the `Settings->Permalinks` and save the settings (with no edit). This will regenerate `.htaccess` file in the sub-directory to include `/wordpress` path in it)

Now everything should work fine.

**UPDATE:** When you save the Permalinks, `.htaccess` file in the sub-directory would be something like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And `.htaccess` in the root directory:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Note the differences in `RewriteBase` rule and the last `RewriteRule` rule. By adding these lines, WP would tell Apache, how to load the website by accessing the root directory of localhost (in addition to the edit in the root `index.php`). These .htaccess files are the reason that there's is no need to re-configure Apache.

**UPDATE2:** I usually use XAMPP on Windows, and Apache rewrite_module is activated bu default on it. Digging around WAMP, I found that this module isn't activated by default on WAMP. This may be the reason .htaccess files are not working on your setup. See these links to activate this module. [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321990/htaccess-not-working-on-wamp) , [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231857/htaccess-doesnt-work-in-wampserver-2-5)

I hope this would help you.

Comment: This works, only if I change apache's httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf to serve my document root in to www/mysite folder first. Tried your way without first doing this and it wouldn't serve the site files to localhost without first pointing to it in apache configuration.  Thanks!

Comment: It's unusual. Did you copy index.php and .htaccess to root and edit the header in the index and saved the permas? As I said, It's possible to this without editing Apache conf. Those two .htaccess files tell Apache to load the site from sub-dir  see this: [shot](https://imgur.com/a/hDl1KsD) I'll update the answer with details on .htaccess files. anyway, glad it helped

Comment: see my second update

Comment: without telling apache on WAMP which file to serve, it gives me a WAMP configuration-like page and doesn't let me log in. When I tell it to serve /www/mysite it automatically does the first step you mentioned, wordpress url: /wordpress and then I just change localhost/ and it works!

Comment: As I mentioned in my second update, you have to enable `rewrite_module` to do it without re-configuring Apache and in this case, if you got stuck at login after changing the addresses, use /wp-login.php instead of /wp-admin and save Permalinks after logged in.

Comment: Okay thank you for all your help. You mentioned the docs above, all I could find was the instructions for when its on a www.com. Where did you find those instructions for step 1 in the docs?

Comment: Apache sees no difference between a localhost setup and a online server. It's just the matter of name resolution. You can even use an IP address there.

Comment: I see what you're saying, just the difference would be in the .htaccess file on the URL rewrite rules for the extra folder...